# What gets printed when you print a object of some class in python?

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I want to ask about this specific example, taken from the [official pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-neural-networks-tutorial-py).

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # 1 input image channel, 6 output channels, 3x3 square convolution
        # kernel
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 3)
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 6 * 6, 120)  # 6*6 from image dimension
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

net = Net()
print(net)
```

And the output is

```
Net(
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=576, out_features=120, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=120, out_features=84, bias=True)
  (fc3): Linear(in_features=84, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

As I understand, this code defines a child class `Net` of `nn.Module`, and defines in its initializer the members `conv1`, `conv2`, etc. These members are printed when `print(net)` is called. Based on this obsevation, I thought that if I add the line `self.x = 0` to the initializer of `Net`, there would be an extra line of output, something like: `(x): 0`. But that didn't happen. So who decides which part of `Net` gets printed?

Comment: I think only the submodules of `nn` module gets printed.

Comment: *"who decides which part"* - https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c7bf4d22fe7f0de239feeb084682827c3b9a759f/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1123-L1146

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

> **repr(object)**
>   Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(), otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a __repr__() method.

Since your class inherits the nn.Module class, it uses its [repr method](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/6249d7302b7277864ed0ade93f58d88ee0cd3aa8/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1123-L1146)

Comment: Also good to mention that it would print out whatever is defined in the `__str__`-method (to be more exact). But if that dunder-method is missing (which is the case here), there is a fallback to `__repr__`. At least, every class *should* have a `__repr__` method (with useful information, of course), at least. Because then you will also get an appropriate output if you print out a container object with this object in it.